# While flashing , is it necessary to unlock the bootloader?

Tags: bootloader

If need to be unlocked tha bootloader.  How can i unlock the bootloader ? For lava pixel v1 android 6.0

Comment: It has mediatek chipset. This issue of unlocking bootloader or not doesn't arise for devices with MTK chipset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lava has a Mediatek chipset (MT6582), you don't have to unlock the bootloader because MTK devices don't have it.

You'll need SP Flashtool and a ROM (with scatter file) and you're done.

You may want to see this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lava-pixel-v1/general/lava-pixel-v1-flash-stock-frimware-t3544011) on XDA Developers forum  on flashing a Lava Pixel phone.